# json works on localhost but not working on my real server

Tags: java, php, android, json, server

I have an application that is getting information from my server (online), I have a version of that website in my computer (localhost),

**The application is working on localhost can get the json, But I can't have access to the website that is on server.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText etResponse;
    TextView tvIsConnected;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get reference to the views
        etResponse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResponse);
        tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);

        // check if you are connected or not
        if(isConnected()){
            tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
     //       tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
        }
        else{
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
        }



        // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
       new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://alarbaeen.com/app/?a=gallery&b=images&c=new&d=1");
    }

    public static String GET(String url){

        Log.i("hamid", "1111111111111");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            Log.i("hamid", "222222222222");
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            Log.i("hamid", "333333333333333333");


            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            Log.i("hamid", "44444444444444444");

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            Log.i("hamid", "55555555555555");

            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
                return true;
            else
                return false;  
    }
    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            return GET(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            etResponse.setText(result);
       }
    }
```

These are the errors:

```
 03-12 11:45:38.704: I/hamid(4005): 1111111111111
03-12 11:45:38.704: I/hamid(4005): 222222222222
03-12 11:45:38.704: I/hamid(4005): 333333333333333333
03-12 11:45:39.524: I/PGA(4005): Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 4005, tid = 4005
03-12 11:45:39.534: I/PGA(4005): New SOCKET connection: com.example.testjsons22 (pid 4005, tid 4005)
03-12 11:45:39.534: W/dalvikvm(4005): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95d67b20)
03-12 11:45:39.534: I/Process(4005): Sending signal. PID: 4005 SIG: 9
03-12 11:45:39.534: D/AndroidRuntime(4005): procName from cmdline: com.example.testjsons22
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.testjsons22
03-12 11:45:39.534: D/AndroidRuntime(4005): file written successfully with content: com.example.testjsons22 StringBuffer : ;com.example.testjsons22
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005): Process: com.example.testjsons22, PID: 4005
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at com.example.testjsons22.MainActivity.GET(MainActivity.java:78)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at com.example.testjsons22.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:108)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at com.example.testjsons22.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-12 11:45:39.534: E/AndroidRuntime(4005):     ... 4 more
```

*note: This program is working in all the hosts and servers, and I think the problem is from my server. (Maybe)*.

Comment: did you get a response from that server ? most likely that is missing

Comment: @PankajNimgade Yes I get answer and I can see json by browser, but Not working for mobile, I mean I can't get  string

Comment: @LASH: somewhere using `Log.i` with passing any message so what is line number `77` in MainActivity

Comment: on right hand side of you code editor (android studio or eclipse) you will see a border right click on it then click show line number, what you get from the server is not properly received by your code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK that was for before. and I don't have that problem yet. Thanks

Comment: @LASH: then share current log

Comment: are you omit some code in `doInBackground`?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Please see the code again, I changed and updated the code

Comment: @Xcihnegn In doInBackground I called the GET class.

Comment: @PankajNimgade Plesae see the code again.

Comment: are you using log or println inside `doInBackground?` error show you have problem there

Comment: `println needs a message` It is very clear that you have the NullPointerException in `.MainActivity.GET(MainActivity.java:78)`. Which line is that? I Think in the catch block and e==null.